# Trying to get property of non-object for images

Tags: laravel

In one of my "show" pages, namely my /anime/1 route, the images display fine. However /anime/2 thru 156, I get a "Trying to get property 'src' of non-object".

I was wondering why it would work fine for one page, but not for the others?

Controller:

```
public function show(Anime $anime)
{
    return view('show', compact('anime'));
}
```

Models:

**App\Anime**

```
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class);
}
```

**App\Episode**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasOne(EpisodeImages::class);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($anime->episodes as $episode)
    <div>{{$episode->id}}</div>
    <div>{{$episode->name}}</div>
    <div>{{$episode->sypnosis}}</div>

    <div><img src="{{$episode->images->src}}"></div>

    <b>{{round($episode->rating())}}</b>
    <br /><br />
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's simply because that anime (which id is 2) doesn't have image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the information exists and it is correct. You can use:

```
{{dd($episode->images->src)}}
```

Maybe the information for some cases is null or empty. At this case, the object don't exists so no object...

Perhaps it is convenient fix the model to always send a information, even if it is null.

Maybe you can try:

```
@if(isset($episode->image->src) && $episode->image->src!="")
<div><img src="{{$episode->images->src}}"></div>
@endif
```

Howerver I recomend strongly that it uses Storage to check if file exists:

```
@if(isset($episode->image->src) && Storage->disk('yourdiskname')->exists($episode->image->src))
<div><img src="{{Storage->disk('yourdiskname')->url($episode->images->src)}}"></div>
@endif
// maybe else and show default img.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do you think you can explain a way where I can retrieve images in the following manner: An anime has 12 episodes each, and on the page where I display the episodes: anime/{id}, I would like for each individual image to have it's picture. anime/1 works, but I would also like it for anime/2 to work as well.

What I'm struggling on is Eloquent where my relationship for Episode.php is 

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(EpisodeImages::class,);
    }

Comment: It's important check if you have a correct model of  information. If eloquent not found an element, return null. If you don't have this element, it's probably that you will have an error. Obviously because, the element don't exists.
A solution may be to fix the model. If you have one episode and you and image you need have a relationship, between both.

Comment: In Image table you need a field episode_id an one relationship One to Many o One to One if this is one to one. After in the controller: you will load this relation:
$data['episodes']=App\Episode::all->with('images');
->with('image') // Load images and put with each related item :)
Maybe you can check if this item exists. If not exist create an empty object or load a default object to avoid errors. :D